# Inserting a record to MongoDB from an axios post

Tags: php, mongodb, vue.js

I have an object i am receiving from a webpage and the data is posted using axios. The object looks like this

```
{
  "select_6": "serviced_apartments",
  "select_9": "4",
  "textarea_12": "hellow",
  "property_files": [
    {
      "url": "uploads/60981ef6d9328.png"
    },
    {
      "url": "uploads/60981ef6df377.png"
    },
    {
      "url": "uploads/60981ef6dba11.png"
    }
  ],
  "bathtub": true,
  "property_owner": "Adam the great",
  "property_name": "Eco bank building",
  "property_address": "College House",
  "property_country": "UK",
  "property_region": "England",
  "property_city": "London",
  "property_coordinates": "66337,3783893",
  "property_district": "Roadmen Pavillion"
}
```

I want to insert into a mongodb database and this is the php script i am using

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *'); 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->dev->customers;

$document = array( 
      "data" => "$requestBody"
   );
$collection->insertOne($document);

?>
```

The php code only inserts into mongodb the object id but not my data. I tried receiving my posted data with `$input_data = $_POST;` i am not able to insert.

How can i receive the data from vue form and insert it in a way that it can be queried?

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert it to a php object first

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");

// takes raw data from the request 
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Converts it into a PHP object 
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->dev->customers;

$collection->insertOne($data);

?>
```